# Org-mode code block evaluation

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In Org-mode, I'm trying to "pipe" data from a little Python 2-liner into Gnuplot, but I cannot figure out how to do that properly (the Gnuplot images remains at 0kb). That's how far I've got in the meanwhile:

```
 #+NAME: foo
 #+begin_src python :exports code
   import random
   for x in range (0,300):
    print random.randrange(1000), random.randrange(1000)
 #+end_src

#+begin_src gnuplot :file gnuplot.png :exports results
  reset
  plot call_foo notitle
 #+end_src
```

Who can make this work?

Answer (score 1):

My gnuplot in emacs isn't working currently so I can't give a full working answer.  However, the `:exports` property for the python bit should be `output`, not `code`.  Furthermore, to have access to this data within the gnuplot session, you'll likely want to read it in as a table.  So if you have your python code as:

```
#+name: foo
#+begin_src python :exports results
  import random
  for x in range(0,300):
      print random.randrange(1000), random.randrange(1000)
#+end_src
```

you'll want your gnuplot session to read in the table of results as a variable

```
#+name: plot-it(data = foo)
#+begin_src gnuplot :file gnuplot.png
  plot data notitle
#+end_src
```

You may need to do some processing on the `data` variable within the gnuplot code to make sure it is the appropriate format.  As I stated above, I can't test this currently, but it should be a starting point.

Comment: I've proceeded some further, please see below.

Answer (score 0):

I've proceeded a little bit further with the two questions, how can I bring Python to put out an Org tabular, and how this could be evaluated by another Gnuplot block: Python could do

1. *return [1, 2, 3]*
2. *print "| 1 | 2 | 3 |"* for *:results output raw*
3. or *print [a, b, c]* for *:results output table*

I've succeedes with evalutation with this code blocks here:

```
#+name: foo
#+begin_src python :results output raw :exports code
  import random
  out="| %s | %s |"
  for x in range(0, 300):
          pair=(random.randrange(1000), random.randrange(1000))
          print out % pair
#+end_src

#+begin_src gnuplot :var data=foo :file gnuplot.png :exports results
  reset
  set terminal png size 500,375
  plot data u 1:2 notitle
#+end_src
```

However, with this setup I always have to execute the Python block "by hand" to generate *#+results: foo* block (which includes lines like: *| 629 | 884 |*), and couldn't bring it to auto-evaluation so far.

**EDIT:** Replaced `#+srcname:` with `#+name:` because `#+srcname:` is obsolete since Orgmode 7.8. The previous version of the Orgmode code with `#+srcname:` [confused another user](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/48662/2370).