# How do I get org-mode to execute code blocks consistently

Tags: org-mode

I'm running R code blocks in a session in an org-mode file, and I can usually get them to execute by C-c C-c, as expected.

I think the pertinent PROPERTY lines I've put at the top of my file are

```
#+PROPERTY: session *R*
#+PROPERTY: cache yes
#+PROPERTY: exports both
#+PROPERTY: tangle yes
```

Sometimes, nothing happens when I press C-c C-c.  AFAICT, that's a seemingly random event; the same code block may work one time and fail another time.

When such a block fails, I do see the results echoed to the minibuffer, but I don't see any results (e.g., a new data frame, as I would have expected in many cases) in the R session.

If I press C-' to edit the code block and then press C-j on each line (or C-r on each region), the code does execute, and the results get echoed appropriately to the org file and show up in the R session.

Here are some sample code block begin lines:

```
#+begin_src R :results silent :exports code 

#+begin_src R :results value :colnames yes :exports both
```

I tested both just now by doing rm(list=ls()), running the code blocks, and doing ls() in the session to see if the results were there.

The first block is simple:

```
#+begin_src R :results silent :exports code 
require(stringr)
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)
require(arm)
require(YaleToolkit)
require(stinepack)
require(mixtools)
require(lubridate)
source("utilities.R")
pf <- function (x,y) {
z <- sqrt(x * x + y * y)
return(x/z)
}
#+end_src
```

In two tests, it worked once and failed once, as detected by looking for pf in the R session.

If important, I can try to produce an ECM that fails frequently enough to be useful, but I suspect this may be a common setup or version problem that someone has seen and solved.  It seems related to [Org-mode code block evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456714/org-mode-code-block-evaluation/9462567#9462567), but the solution there seems to have been to :export results.  In most cases, I use :exports both, which would seem to cover that case, and, in at least some cases, I care about setting up the environment in the session and not exporting to the org file.  I'm never passing data through org-mode; I'm only using the session for that.

BTW, I'm running org-mode 7.8.03 on GNU Emacs 23.3.1 on XP Pro 64.

Comment: Are you certain it isn't just the fact that `cache` is set to `yes` and the content simply hasn't changed so no re-evaluation is necessary?

Comment: Maybe.  I'll try it as soon as I'm back in a position to do so.  In the meantime, I did (re-)discover that deleting any results section below a code block and then typing C-c C-c will cause the block to execute, so your suggestion sounds credible.  The manual seems to say it will never cache results if :session is used, and I figured that carried over to a PROPERTY entry.